# don't know the number of rows in section (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my conception every row of tableview is kind of task which you can fill in.And every time you open the app one row should be a priori on a tableView. (As you see in picture )[image]

Also I have button which  allows you to add a row.
But I have no idea how can I know the number of rows in section.
Can you please help me with it ?(In my code I've commented the moments I can't understand)

```
class TaskSecondViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource{

 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear

 @IBAction func insert_rows(_ sender: Any) {

   let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 1) // Don't know what to write in "row"
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 1 // Here also
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TaskTableViewCell

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Somewhere you will need to store your rows. And this data source will surely be capable of telling you the items it stores, thus the number of rows in the section.

Answer (score 4):

have you tried this :

> `yourTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)`

this returns the no of rows in your table view's section

Answer (score 2):

You can simply have

```
var numOfRow = 0
```

every time you hit the button

```
numberOfRow += 1
tableView.reloadData()
```

so you can return numberOfRow

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

return numOfRow
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I have no idea how can I know the number of rows in section.

The important thing to understand is that a table knows nothing about the items it displays, or how to display them, or what to do when people interact with them. A table is really just a list of sections, where each section is a list of cells. And it can scroll. And it can ask for help.

The items that are displayed are kept elsewhere. They don't even exist as rows in the table all at the same time. The table only keeps as many rows as it needs to display, and when the user scrolls, it asks some other object for more rows to display and throws out the rows that are no longer displayed. That other object is the data source, and it may be the 'elsewhere' where the items are kept, or it may only be an object that knows where to find (or generate) those items.

In this case, your `TaskSecondViewController` view controller is the table's data source. You need make sure that that controller somehow has access to the data it needs. Maybe it reads the list from a file. Maybe an array of items is passed in from some other object. There are a million variations on the theme, but it's up to you to know what you want to display in the table and to know where those things are kept. Once you know that, you should be able to figure out how many items are in a given section. You're also going to need to know how many sections there are. It could be that you just have one list of items, and you don't plan to break it up into sections; in that case, you'll just return `1` for the number of sections and the number of items in the whole list for the number of rows in that section.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add a row, you don't have to insert it into the table view at an explicit spot. It would be easier to have an array (or dictionary or whatever) and add your items into that object, and then reload your table view when items are added.

```
var itemsToDisplay = [SomeObject]

override func viewDidLoad() { 

    // populate items if needed

}

@IBAction func insert_rows(_ sender: Any) {

   // get your data to create your object
   // add your object to itemsToDisplay
   itemsToDisplay.append(myObject)

   // for a TableViewController
   self.tableView.reloadData()

   // if you've included the tableView as an @IBOutlet
   myTableView.reloadData()

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return itemsToDisplay.count // this might be zero, but it doesn't matter
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TaskTableViewCell

    var item = itemsToDisplay[indexPath.row]

    cell.titleLabel.text = item.whatever

    return cell
}
```